# How do I write a query in DynamoDB Go SDK with equal condition for the partition key but a MAX for the sort key for a set of partition values?

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a table in DynamoDB with a composite key

user_id (PartitionKey)
timestamp (Sort Key)

I want to retrieve a group of items, I have a set of user_ids I want to retrieve but I also need the timestamp to be the MAX for every single user_id.

For example:

| user_id | timestamp | attr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1614910613 | value1 |
| 1 | 1614902527 | value 2 |
| 2 | 1614910683 | value 2 |
| 2 | 1614881311 | value 2 |
| 3 | 1614902527 | value 2 |

I want to retrieve the rows for user_id 1 and 2, with the max timestamp for each user. In this case, my result set should be:

| user_id | timestamp | attr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1614910613 | value1 |
| 2 | 1614910683 | value 2 |

I can do this now on an item-by-item basis doing this Key expression:

```
cond := expression.KeyAnd(
    expression.Key("user_id").Equal(expression.Value(userId)),
    expression.Key("timestamp").LessThanEqual(expression.Value(int32(time.Now().Unix()))),
    )
expr, err:= expression.NewBuilder().WithKeyCondition(cond).Build()

if err!=nil {
    panic(err)
}

input := &dynamodb.QueryInput{
    ExpressionAttributeNames: expr.Names(),
    ExpressionAttributeValues: expr.Values(),
    KeyConditionExpression: expr.KeyCondition(),
    TableName: aws.String("td.notes"),
    Limit: aws.Int64(1),
    ScanIndexForward: aws.Bool(false),
}
```

My problem is, I don't know how to pass a set of values for the user_id key instead of a single value. I took a look at the BatchGetItem, I know I can do something like this:

```
mapOfAttrKeys := []map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{}

for _, place := range userIDs {
    mapOfAttrKeys = append(mapOfAttrKeys, map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
        "user_id": &dynamodb.AttributeValue{
            S: aws.String(place),
        },
        "timestamp": &dynamodb.AttributeValue{
            N: aws.String(timestamp),
        },
    })
}

input := &dynamodb.BatchGetItemInput{
    RequestItems: map[string]*dynamodb.KeysAndAttributes{
        tableName: &dynamodb.KeysAndAttributes{
            Keys: mapOfAttrKeys,
        },
    },
}
```

But I cannot put a "less than" condition in the timestamp.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetItem and BatchGetItem require the exact primary key.

You'll need to issue separate Query() for each user you want to return.

The key to returning max, is as you've found

```
Limit: aws.Int64(1),
ScanIndexForward: aws.Bool(false),
```

You really shouldn't even need this

```
expression.Key("timestamp").LessThanEqual(expression.Value(int32(time.Now().Unix())))
```